# Error in deploying Angular Full-stack application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, deployment, web-deployment, angular-fullstack

I tried to build and deploy my angular full-stack project on an Linux machine. 
I have only git and nodejs installed on my machine and I ran this "$ NODE_ENV=production node ./server" command (https://angular-fullstack.github.io/deployment/).

I am getting an error "cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/set-immediate'". Did I miss anything?

Comment: did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes I it was also unsuccessful [log file](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/2667)

Comment: Your error, from the log file, says: `112 error Failed at the demo@0.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.` It looks like `typings` is related to TypeScript: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings. Either there is an NPM script you need to run or you have something like Gulp or Grunt that need to be run. Can you post your `package.json` file?

Comment: @Intervalia Yes I am using both TypeScipt and Gulp in this project which is auto-conigured by Angular full-stack generator. I have attached the package.json file here:  [package.json](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/2667) Thank you.

Comment: So your `package.json` file has this line: `postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/typings install",`. Is there an executable file in the `./node_modules/.bin` folder? Also you show that you are using typings version 0.8.1 (April 2016) but it is up to version 2.1.1 (April 2017) Could it be incompatible versions? I am running out of ideas to help.

Comment: @Intervalia Thanks for you here. The issue is solved now. [Ref. solution](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/2667)

Comment: So what was the issue?

Comment: the issue comes from a compression library called shrink-ray, which depends on iltorb. It is explained in this [link](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/2667) .